# Purge or Remove Old data from Azure SQL Warehouse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Trying to understand based on some knowledge that If some old data needs to purged in the Azure warehouse table (with partitions) then what is the ideal way ?

1. Create New table with same schema
2. Switch wanted partitions to the new table
3. Drop Old table with stale partition
4. Rename New table to Old table

Is CTAS really required in this scenario? Came across this question and the opinion seems divided.

[Remove Data older than 36 months](https://www.examtopics.com/discussions/microsoft/view/14136-exam-dp-200-topic-1-question-28-discussion/)

Comment: You say is CTAS really needed, but CTAS offers you a way to easily recreate an empty version of the same with the same distribution - so why not use it?

Comment: Well of course there are some answers for the question posted. I am looking for the "ideal way". CTAS I believe would take more time and resources to achieve the objective.